# How to exclude standard libs from shared libraries

Tags: c++

I have one executable which statically links standard libraries (libstdc++ and libgcc) and many shared objects that also statically link standard libraries. I want to exclude statically linking standard libraries by shared objects and let them use the one that is linked in the executable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: You probably don't link *all* of the standard library into your executable, right? So some functions would be missing anyway. (Not using static linking at all seems like a more feasible strategy).

Comment: Yeah, but I think --whole-archive option can help. Is it a good idea though?